# Torsors are geometric quotients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

I have been reading lately a lot about torsors in algebraic geometry and some authors say that a torsor over a scheme $X$, which is defined as a faithfully flat map of finite type $f:P\rightarrow X$ such that the natural morphism
$$P\times G\simeq P\times_{X}P$$
is an isomorphism is a geometric quotient. I can prove the first three conditions of Mumford's definition, but I don't know how to prove that $O_{X}=f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{P}^{G}$. Can you help me or at least provide me with some references? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: There is a pullback map $f^*:\mathcal O_X\to f_*\mathcal O_P^G$ which becomes the isomorphism $\mathcal O_P\cong (p_2)_*(\mathcal O(P\times G)^G)$ after pullback along the faithfully flat map $f$. By faithfully flat descent, it must already have been an isomorphism. (Note that the definition of torsor also includes the fiberwise $G$-action on $P$ which is needed to state the condition you give.)

Comment: Well, that's not actually true. Since $f$ is faithfully flat you can just check that $\mathcal{O}_{P}=f^{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X})\rightarrow f^{\ast}(f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{P}^{G})$ is an isomorphism. Due to the condition we have imposed, it holds that $f^{\ast}f_{\ast} \mathcal{O}_{P}=p_{1,\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{P\times G})$ I don't know how to conclude from those facts. Let us recall that I am not imposing qc hypothesis nor on the map $f$ nor on the schemes considered.

Comment: @SamanthaSmith  The claim that the pullback map $f^*$ to the $G$-invariants is an isomorphism is local on the target.  So you may assume that $X$ is quasi-compact.  Since $P$ is faithfully flat over $X$, there exists a quasi-compact open subset $U$ of $P$ such that also $U$ is faithfully flat over $X$ (and also quasi-compact).  So you can restrict to $U$ the pullback of $f^*$ to $P$.

Comment: And how you can conclude from those assumptions @JasonStarr?

Comment: @SamanthaSmith: Finite type implies quasicompact by definition.

Comment: Okey, thats true @LaurentMoret-Bailly, but how we can conclude that the structural ring of the base is identified with the invariants of the direct image. I think it should be easy to conclude but I don't see why.

Comment: What step of Bertram Arnold's argument do you think is wrong? (1) Write down the pullback map (2) Compute the pullback of the pullback map (3) Check it is an isomorphism (4) Conclude the original map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Well,  The point is that I don't know how to prove the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{P}\simeq (p_{2})_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{P\times G}^{G})$.  @WillSawin

Comment: (1) I guess it's supposed to be $( (p_1)*  \mathcal O_{P times G})^G$. (2) The inverse map is given by pulling back along the identity-section $P \to P \times G$. Checking the composition in one direction is the identity is automatic. In the other direction, you can check it using the definition of $G$-invariant.